# Google Dialogflow Quick Replies formatting issues in Telegram

Tags: dialogflow-es, telegram, chatbot, telegram-bot, facebook-messenger

I had create a chatbot using Dialogflow and integrated it with Facebook Messenger & Telegram. I noticed that for the Quick Replies in Telegram (Link 1) appears differently in FB Messenger (Link 2). Is there any way to make it nicer and more presentable in Telegram?

[Telegram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0F7S.jpg)

[Facebook Messenger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqnk3.jpg)

This is my Quick Replies settings in Dialogflow.

[Dialogflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2RWju.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in DialogFlow you can indeed (as Marc pointed out) use a Custom Payload for Telegram, here it is an example:

```
{
  "telegram": {
    "text": "What would you like help with?",
    "reply_markup": {
      "inline_keyboard": [
        [
          {
            "text": "Daily News",
            "callback_data": "news"
          }
        ],
        [
          {
            "text": "New Features",
            "callback_data": "features"
          }
        ]
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The quick replies appear a buttons you can click (notice the actual response is sent but not displayed within the chat).

All the best!

Beppe

Answer (score 0):

**SHORT ANSWER**:

That is NOT possible.

**DETAILED ANSWER**:

Each Channel (Facebook Messenger, Telegram etc.) has its own UI components and its own styling. Those can't be changed as they are **rendered/controlled by the channel it self**.

What Dialogflow doing is giving you the ability to show these UI components in each channel without making you handle the different implementation needed for each channel.

Dialogflow also gives you the ability to send Custom Payloads where you can send a custom JSON (that should be compatible with the channel you are connected to) That can be used if the channel for example has a UI component that is not yet supported by Dialogflow.

**If** the channel gives you an option to change a property in the UI components you are using, you could do that using Custom JSON, But still you are always limited to how each channel renders the UI components and what features they provide us